# Grails 2.3.5 on Tomcat 6 - compatibility issues?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I was wondering if anyone had a luck deploying Grails 2.3.5 to Tomcat6

In BuildConfig I have ***grails.servlet.version = "2.5"***

Plugins block looks like following:

```
plugins {
    build ":release:3.0.1"
    build ":tomcat:7.0.50"

    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'

    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.7"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
    runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
}
```

On the startup I get following exception:

> ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/servlet/AsyncContext

It starts up perfectly fine on Tomcat7. I have a suspicion that hibernate plugin is dragging hard dependency on Servlet 3, but that's just a guess at this stage.

Comment: Does your generated .war include the file `WEB-INF/lib/grails-plugin-async-2.3.5.jar`?  If so, try explicitly excluding that plugin. More details in a JIRA ticket that sounds similar: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9788

Comment: Also check `application.properties` for the proper `app.servlet.version`.

Comment: I've added servlet version to application.properties - same result.

Comment: I've removed the dependency on grails-pligin-async and it starts up fine, but only if I also remove dependency to org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.1 and org.grails.plugins:hibernate:3.6.10.7, cause hibernate depends on async and doesn't startup if I exclude it and cache depends on hibernate... As a result I don't think combination of latest grails + tomcat6 + hibernate can actually work, unless anyone can suggest version of hibernate plugin that doesn't have this problem

Comment: I'm a bit new to grails.... how did you remove the grails-async plugin?  I'd thought this would work: `grails.project.dependency.resolution = { inherits("global") { excludes([group:'org.grails', name:'grails-async']) } ...` but the `WEB-INF/lib/grails-plugin-async-2.3.7.jar` is still present in the war file produced from a `grails war` command.

Comment: I was using maven to build the project. In BuildConfig I had "pom true" and set all dependencies in pom.xml. However as I mentioned earlier you cannot use hibernate with this combination because of dependency chain it has. In the end of the day we managed to just upgrade to tomcat7.

Answer (score 1):

For me upgrading to latest minor version solve this issue.

- Make sure you upgrade to the latest version of the Grails 2.3.x (currently 2.3.11).
  It is as easy as changing the value in the application.properties
- In your BuildConfig.groovy make sure to set
  grails.servlet.version = "2.5"

After these changes the Grails up could be deployed into Tomcat 6.0.x container.

Hope it helps
Eduardo