# Grails 2.3.8 with Tomcat 6

Tags: grails, tomcat7, tomcat6, grails-2.3

Is it possible to run grails 2.3.8 app on Tomcat 6? I am trying ot deploy my app on appfrog and I am getting errors related to asynservlet.

So far I have tried changing `grails.servlet.version = "2.5"`in buildconfig.groovy which still ended up in throwing run time exception.

Is there a valid value that I can change in `build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"` tag? I tried putting tomcat:6.0 and tomcat:6.0.51 with no avail!

**UPDATE**

If I add the following in my Buildconfig

```
inherits("global") {
    excludes group: 'org.grails', module:'grails-async'
    // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
```

I get the following exception

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
Error |
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Error |
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Error |
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/AntMain
Error |
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error |
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error |
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error |
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error |
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error |
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a known issue have a look at [this](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9788) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693496/grails-2-3-5-on-tomcat-6-compatibility-issues)

hope this helps.